# A Question on the paper "A Simple Computation of Zeta 2k"

Tags: recurrence-relations, riemann-zeta

On the fourth page in deriving (5), it says that it can be easily obtained from

$I(k,m)=-\frac{2k(2k-1)}{m^2\pi^2}I(k-1,m)$

that

$I(k,m)=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(2k)!}{m^{2k}\pi^{2k}}$ for m even, and 0 otherwise.

Here $I(k,m)=\int_0^1B_{2k}(t)cos(m\pi t)dt$ where $B_k(t)$ is the Bernoulli Polynomial.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5030.pdf

I must be missing something but I don't see the connection

Comment: the connection to what ? And probably $I(0,m) = B_{m+1}$ and your 1st formula gives $I(k,m)=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(2k)!}{m^{2k}\pi^{2k}} I(0,m)$